# How do I do exponential or natural log in Django?

Tags: python, django, numpy

I have a formula, say, `trustworthy = mt.exp(np.log(age) + wealth**2)`. I know this is written using numpy and math in Python. Nonetheless, I am not sure how to implement this in Django.

What I did was

```
from django.db.models.functions import Power,Ln,Exp
trustworthy = Exp(Ln(age) + wealth*wealth)
```

Nonetheless, there was an error and when I print out trustworthy, it became a string: Exp(Ln(Value(55))) + 16

Thanks a lot for helping !

Comment: The functions from `django.db.models.functions` are supposed to be used inside a queryset. What are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: I was trying to return a number. Just realized I don't need django.db.models.functions. Normal math library from Python  works